# Load testing GUI application

Tags: c++, opengl, load

We are developing a PC application that runs on Windows.

What would be a good approach for the developers to get some kind of load testing done before it goes to Test? -

1. Using an already existing tool for GUI testing like Selenium? Any other easy to use tool? Our code is in C++ (Open GL) on Windows.
2. Add a test stub within our code to simulate a load of the events that would get generated every time a button is clicked.
3. Use of a run time memory leak tool like Purify Plus or drmemory

We are developers and are primarily looking at some bare minimum load tests before the test team runs extensive tests.

Is a combination of #2 and #3 or just #3 helpful for this?

Please let me know if you have any other comments..

Answer (score -1):

So you typically don't `load test` desktop applications unless that application is making calls to your server (in that case you would be load testing the sever).

I've never seen a desktop application which isn't able to handle user load on a single desktop. Unless you are querying a db on the user's desktop and need to worry about loading a massive amount of data and pegging the CPU, you should be fine.

When programming in C/C++, I've found `GNU gprof` invaluable in building a program which successfully utilizes the CPU's cache. `GNU gprof` is really invaluable beacuse it will provide you with  the flat profile tool, which will give you the total execution time spent in each function and its percentage of the total running time, along with function call counts.

For UI desktop application testing, these two tools are really great and have been recommended by Joel (from Joel on Software):

- [TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools/)
- [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)

You can learn more about about `GNU gprof` [here](https://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html).

Answer (score -1):

Both Silk Performer and Load Runner offer GUI load testing support.  I've used both and have ran up to 250 Virtual User loads which have simulated a few thousand users per/day. I've sometimes have run into applications where all protocol level load testing tools don't support the applications and the GUI approach works great. I've also been learning to Selenium with JMeter to run the GUI load tests but getting the selenium script to be reliable has been very difficult. If you run into application that don't need huge amounts of users you'll find the GUI approach to be much faster and sometime more accurate than the protocol based approach.